# Error while testing QT test project

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake, ubuntu

I have started using QT on Kubuntu. I first installed g++ via Package Manager. Then I installed QT 5.0.1. I then made a test project to check if everything is correct or not. Then I got following issues.
- cannot find -lGL
- collect2: error:Id returned 1 exit status

I saw in Compile Output

```
11:32:05: Running steps for project untitled2...
11:32:05: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:32:05: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -w
make: Entering directory `/home/harsh/Desktop/untitled2-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_GCC_64bit-Debug'
g++ -m64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/harsh/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/harsh/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib -o untitled2 main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow. -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/home/harsh/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [untitled2] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/harsh/Desktop/untitled2-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_GCC_64bit-Debug'
11:32:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled2 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Please help me fix these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Qt != QT

The error tells you what is wrong, the compiler cannot find `libGL.so`.  It's usually in /usr/lib64.